# Error replicating Highcharts Dashboard demo on Angular 16

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I'm trying to replicate [this demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pc4xsk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) using Angular 16, and get this error:

> Error:
> node_modules/@highcharts/dashboards/es-modules/Dashboards/Plugins/HighchartsPlugin.d.ts:9:9
>
> - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'KPI' must be of type 'typeof KPIComponent', but here
>   has type 'typeof KPIComponent'.
>
> 9         KPI: typeof KPIComponent;
> ~~~
>
> node_modules/@highcharts/dashboards/es-modules/Dashboards/Components/KPIComponent.d.ts:264:9
> 264         KPI: typeof KPIComponent;
> ~~~
> 'KPI' was also declared here.

Any ideas how to fix this? I installed the latest highcharts dashboard version 1.2.0

**UPDATE**

This is how I see the dashboard now:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error has already been fixed, has been merged and is on the master: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/pull/20323

As a workaround you can import this version directly:

```
import Dashboards from '@highcharts/dashboards/es-modules/masters/dashboards.src'
```

Comment: Thanks, I will wait until you release a new version

Comment: I installed version 1.2.1 and now get an error in the console: The component is misconfigured and is unable to find the HTML cell element title to render the content.

Comment: Please see screenshot in the question

Comment: Without the code it's hard to tell what the problem might be. It would be best if you reproduced this in an online demo using the same versions of the libraries and Angular.

Comment: the import of dashboards.css was missing